# how can I change react-google-maps <DrawingManager> component prop drawingMode props in runtime without change component state

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I'm using react-google-maps lib in my React project. I want that, after complete to draw a shape, the user can't draw anymore and the shape stays on the screen.

I have de flowing snippet:

```js
<GoogleMap
  zoom={16}
  center={initialPosition}
  mapTypeId="satellite"
>
  <DrawingManager
    drawingMode={"polygon"}
    onPolygonComplete={onDrawComplete}
  />
</GoogleMap>
```

With this code, the use can draw any shape that he and how many shapes he want.
I saw that I can change drawingMode of  componente to null.
I've tried to store this value in a component state, but when I tried to change this inside onDrawComplete() callback, the map re-renders and I don't want that behavior.
Question: How can I change this prop to null without use component state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by the following steps:

1. Import the objects from the library:

```
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  Polyline,
  Circle,
  Rectangle,
  Polygon
} from "react-google-maps";
import { DrawingManager } from "react-google-maps/lib/components/drawing/DrawingManager";
```

2. Declare different state variables for each of the overlay. These will be the variables that you will need in creating these different overlay objects. You should also have a variable for `drawingControlEnabled` to set the  value of `options>drawingControl` parameter of Drawing Manager.

```
this.state = {
      drawingControlEnabled: true,
      marker: null,
      polyline: null,
      circleRadius: null,
      circleCenter: null,
      rectangle: null,
      polygon: null,
      visible: true
    };
```

3. Use drawing manager with `onOverlayComplete` parameter where it will go to a function that will listen everytime you are done drawing the overlay.

```
<DrawingManager
          onOverlayComplete={this.overlay}
          defaultOptions={{
            drawingControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
              drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
              ]
            }
          }}
          options={{
            drawingControl: this.state.drawingControlEnabled
          }}
        />
```

4. In the onOverlayComplete function, you should set the `drawingControlEnabled` state to `false`. This will remove the Drawing Controls after the overlays are drawn. You should also have a switch case that will check the condition as to which overlay you had made.  For each condition, get the value from the `event.overlay` for each overlay type and pass the value of the needed parameters for each overlay type in the state variables.

```
  overlay = e => {
    this.setState({
      drawingControlEnabled: false
    });
    console.log(e);
    switch (e.type) {
      case "marker":
        this.setState({
          marker: {
            lat: e.overlay.getPosition().lat(),
            lng: e.overlay.getPosition().lng()
          }
        });
        break;
      case "polyline":
        this.setState({
          polyline: e.overlay.getPath()
        });
        break;
      case "circle":
        this.setState({
          circleRadius: e.overlay.getRadius(),
          circleCenter: e.overlay.getCenter()
        });
        break;
      case "rectangle":
        this.setState({
          rectangle: e.overlay.getBounds()
        });

        break;
      case "polygon":
        this.setState({
          polygon: e.overlay.getPaths()
        });
        break;
    }
  };
```

5. In the render() Area inside the  object, add the different overlay object with the condition that check if the state variables for that object is not null. Doing this will only show the object once the state variables have values from the switch case above.

```
{this.state.marker !== null && <Marker position={this.state.marker} />}

        {this.state.polyline !== null && (
          <Polyline path={this.state.polyline} />
        )}
        {this.state.circleRadius !== null && (
          <Circle
            radius={this.state.circleRadius}
            center={this.state.circleCenter}
            visible={this.state.visible}
          />
        )}

        {this.state.rectangle !== null && (
          <Rectangle bounds={this.state.rectangle} />
        )}
        {this.state.polygon !== null && <Polygon paths={this.state.polygon} />}
```

Here is a [working code sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drawingmanager-onlyonce-qzxybm?file=Map.js). note: Put your API key in the `index.js` for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You need to catch drawingManager reference and do EVERYTHING using this.

Google MAPS and other Google things are like a paralell world (if i can say this).  You need do everything using their instance directly.

google.maps.events.addEventListener
google.maps.events.addDOMListener
... and so on...

In React I couldn't find a way to doit diferent as this:

1. Use onLoad event to reach the drawingManager instance

   ```html
   <DrawingManager onLoad={handlerLoadDrawingManager} ...other />
   ```
2. Create a reference and asign the `drawingManagerInstance` recibed in `handlerLoadDrawingManager`

   ```javascript
   const drawingManager = useRef()

   const handlerLoadDrawingManager = (drawingManagerInstance) => {
       drawingManager.current = drawingManagerInstance
   }
   ```
3. Use `drawingManager.current.setDrawingMode(<some mode>)`

   ```javascript
   const someFunction = () => drawingManager.current.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON)
   ```

   See [drawing manager overlay types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/drawing?hl=en#OverlayType) for more modes.

PDT:  Do the same with map instance, and polygons, and other map object that tyou need interact to